# Assigning one-to-many polygon to .csv data in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.3, relationship-class

So I am currently working with two separate files. One is a polygon feature class detailing a specific countries' subdistricts. These subdistricts are identified using a specific alpha-numeric code. The other file is a .csv file containing information on humanitarian programs currently in place within this country. Each program is identified by its location, down to the subdistrict (using the same code). There are numerous subdistricts with multiple programs.

My end goal is to assign each individual program the polygon of the subdistrict where it is located. To this end, I have created a relationship class between the two (one-to-many). However, it seems this will not help me accomplish my goal.

Is there any way I can accomplish this? One idea would be to export the polygon spatial data to .csv format, allowing a join, but I'm not sure if that is possible.

Comment: What is your goal? You only have two choices with that one (region) to many (program) relationship - a relate (which you say won't work), or duplicate region polygons. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134052/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123064/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110907/

Comment: perhaps a join might be more appropriate but from the sounds of it you want to join the table to the polygons which will not generate geometries in your output. It might be better to separate your programs into individual tables then for each program join the polygons to the table (1 to 1) and select 'matching only' which will not show any polygons that don't have a matching program. Are you trying to do this interactively or would you like to build an arcpy script to do this?

Comment: Agree with Chris and Michael. The easiest way would probably be to [Join or Relate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/tables/about-joining-and-relating-tables.htm) the data. Joins = _one-to-one_ or _many-to-one_. Relates = _one-to-many_ or _many-to-many_.